# Search your computer functionality

Tags: 16.04, search

Why (or how) I cannot see all my apps when I click the "Search your Computer" button in Ubuntu? There are many other apps that I have in my computer that they don't show off there...I played with all the filtering options...and nothing.
For example, all Libre Office, Gimp, Freecad, Atom...all these won't show off when I click this button!

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I found. And understand what was my problem. All of my apps where in the....ehhmm..."Applications" button (I suppose thats the name of the button because of the A) and in the "installed" section, beside the "Home" button. I found this not so intuitive. I thought that all my apps would appear in the "Home" section. Anyway...

Comment: What is the purpose of the "Home" tab? I mean the one in the lower part of the window. I think it is confusing ("Home" tab vs. "Apps" tab)...